# Issues with makefile producing fatal error "Don't know how to make target" using C source files

Tags: c, unix, makefile

I am having an issue with this makefile giving the fatal error: "Don't know how to make target calc.o". The naming is correct along with being in the working directory, and the other issue is that when I switch the order of the object files for default target file it will say it does not know how to make that target either, so the order does not seem to change anything or be one specific file. I am running the make command on a sun sparc unix server as well. The makefile is pasted below:

```
#The following rule tells make about possible suffixes
#(extensions) of file names.
.SUFFIXES: .c .o
#The following definition of CC ensures that
#gcc will be used to compile the C source files.
CC = gcc
#The following definition of CFLAGS ensures that
#the debugger can be used with the executable file (p1)
#created by running make.
CFLAGS = -g
#The following rule tells make how a ".o" file should
#be created from the corresponding ".c" file.
#Note that the "-c" option must be used here since we are
#compiling source files separately. (Note that the line
#following the ".c.o:" line begins with the "tab" character.)
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
#Dependency rule for the default target and how the
#default target is to be created. (Note that the line
#following the dependency rule begins with the "tab"
#character.)
p2: main.o textToBin.o binToText.o calc.o
    gcc main.o textToBin.o binToText.o calc.o -o p2
#Dependency rules for other targets. (We don't need to
#specify how these targets are created since we have already
#given a general rule for creating a ".o" file from the
#corresponding ".c" file.)
#NO HEADER FILES
#Target for removing unnecessary files.
clean:
    rm -f *.o core
```

Comment: Is there a file `calc.c` in your directory?  If so then you should not get this error.  You say you're running on Solaris; are you using Solaris make?  Or did you install GNU make?

Comment: As @MadScientist said, that looks right. Perhaps confirm that `calc.c` exists and is newer than `calc.o`, and run `make` with a 'verbose' option (which is `-d` for GNU Make) to get the program to explain what it thinks its doing.

Comment: Best guess: your C source files are in a different directory than `make`'s working directory.  `make` can handle such situations in a general sense, but it's a function of your `Makefile`.